# Usar "NA" na operação lógico no R

Tags: r

Estou com a situação:

```
a = c(1,2,3, NA, 5, 6, NA)
b = 99
for(i in 1: 7){
  if(a[i] == "NA"){
    a[i] = b
  }
}
```

O problema é que o R não faz a comparação lógica usando "NA" nem NA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na verdade ao fazer a[i] == "NA", você está testando se a[i] é igual a string 'NA'. Para fazer a comparação, você deve usar a função is.na(a[i]).

```
a = c(1,2,3, NA, 5, 6, NA) 
b = 99 
for(i in 1: 7)
{ 
    if(is.na(a[i]))
    {
        a[i] = b 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementando:

Em outros pacotes estatísticos o valor míssing é um número. No SAS, por exemplo, é um número muito pequeno, no Stata é um número muito grande. Então é possível fazer um teste comparando os números de um vetor com o missing, que no fundo é um outro número.

No R, isso não é possível, pois o NA não é número, nem string, é um tipo específico, diferente de dado. Portanto não faz sentido comparar se um vetor v==NA.

É por isso que tem que usar a função. is.na().

Nos outros softwares não tem esta idiossincrazia. Por outro lado, a outra forma de fazer, atribuino valor numério (seja muito grande ou muito pequeno) para missing causa potenciais problemas em alguns testes lógicos (Ex: no Stata  v>0, retornaria não só os valores positivos como os missing de v)